# How to have user input a value for a set Enum and then into the base class?

Tags: java, enums, java.util.scanner

Okay, so I have an enum class of values called MethodOfCook and created it into a field called hi, what I;m trying to do here is allow the user to input  one of the enum values for MethodOfCook to define their recipe.
I apologize if this is very basic, but its only been 2 months since I started coding. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Enum Method

System.out.println("Now select an Enum Method;");

```
    System.out.println("Remember your values are;");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       MethodOfCook bu = hi;
               for (MethodOfCook bum : bu.values())
                        System.out.println(bum);

            while(true)

             // read strings from Scanner - display Algorithm value or throw exception

             try

             {

               System.out.print ("Enter value  ");

               System.out.println("Great, your value is" + bu.valueOf(sc.next()));
                Recipe ji = new Recipe(bud, yesName, jman, bu);
                System.out.println(ji);

               }

             catch (IllegalArgumentException m)

               { System.out.println("  Error: " + m);

             }    

           }
```

Comment: Uhm not really sure what your question is...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I'm trying to get the user to input an enum and then assign what they entered back into a base class.

Answer (score 2):

[`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) is a static method that returns the enum instance you're looking for.

When doing `bu.valueOf(sc.next())` the result of the call is not stored anywhere, and `bu` will not change its value after the invocation.

Also you should be calling it statically on the enum and not on a variable, and assign its result accordingly:

```
bu = MethodOfCook.valueOf(sc.next());
```

Comment: This is what I got when running it?                                                                Now select an Enum Method;
Remember your values are;
GRILL
STOVETOP
MICROWAVE
OVERFRYER
DEFAULT
NUKE
GRENADE
MYRAPS
NUKE
Enter value  Great, your value isNUKE
honroth.funwithrecipes.four.Recipe@2503dbd3

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to do. `honroth.funwithrecipes.four.Recipe@2503dbd3` is what `ji.toString()` returns. You could always override `toString()` in the `Recipe` class to provide prettier/meaningful output based on attributes' values, or print the specific fields you want to print out instead of just printing the whole object with `System.out.println(ji);`